# Popover appearing in the wrong place

Tags: javascript, jquery, popover

**JS Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Xw9QK/1/**

I am making a popover, and had it working, but then when I started loading the content though ajax and adding a spinner to appear first it now appears in the wrong place.

I think the problem is something to do with the fact the spinner makes a small popover appear and when the content loads it uses the same div to add the ajax content then resizes the box before moving it.

Now sometimes it works, on my site it seems to not work first time, but when closing and opening it again it snaps back to the correct position!

Can anyone see whats going wrong here?

I am using this function to reset the position:

```
function reset_popover_position(user_id) {
    var position = $('#link_' + user_id).position();
    console.log(position);
    var top_position = (position.top - $('.new_tooltip').outerHeight()) - 10;
    console.log(top_position);
    var left_position = (position.left - ($('.new_tooltip').outerWidth() / 2) + ($('#link_' + user_id).outerWidth() / 2));
    console.log(left_position);

    $('.new_tooltip').css({
        top: top_position + "px",
        left: left_position + "px"
    });

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `setTimeout` fixed the issue. **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xw9QK/2/)**.

It is a trick that I use when I deal with dynamic contents height & width.

I think it `setTimeout` of `1` gives the browser enough time to render the html & so, when `setTimeout` triggers the actual code that, calculates dimensions, everything gives proper results.

I added `setTimeout` inside `toggle_popover`.

```
setTimeout(function() {
  reset_popover_position(user_id);
}, 1);
```

Comment: That works! But on my site where it's loaded via ajax it seems to appear in the wrong place for 1ms then snap back to the correct place, do you know how to fix that?

Comment: I fixed that as well by using toggle(), I hid it, added the html, reset the position and then toggle'd it again :)

Thanks for your help!